# How to put list items at the bottom of list view in Navigation Drawer like Foursquare

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I got a list view for navigation drawer, how can I put list item like "Add Friends", "Settings" align at the bottom of the list view.

[image]

Update 1
I add a setting view to the footer view.

```
View settingView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
TextView textView = (TextView)settingView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list_item_text_view);
textView.setText("Settings");
drawerListView.addFooterView(settingView);
```

The settings item appear at the last one in the list view successfully. But how can I make it to stick and align at the bottom? Thanks.

Comment: add a footer to your listview

Comment: try to add those both item on listview footer...

Comment: Just edit my post for update 1.

Comment: Someone have idea to do this with recycler view ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764689/android-drawer-with-recyclerview-add-footer-at-bottom

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can put the `ListView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and assign `android:layout_gravity="start"` to the `RelativeLayout`. And set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` property to the view you want to set to bottom of `ListView`.

This may help you.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"...../>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Friends" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, you gave me the key point solution, but I change a little bit for my need. I separated list view into upper list view and bottom list view, and add those two into left_drawer_layout to control drawer open and close. And the bottom list view set layout align parent bottom to true.

Comment: How to add this relative view in Activity? This is really helpful information.  Thanks and repped!

Comment: I am getting classCastException here

Comment: @andrewww the exception comes because you are using the `ListView` reference when calling `mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen()` and open/close. You should use the reference to the `relative_layout`.

Answer (score 2):

Jay Donga was really helpful, but I had to change two methods to insert a footer in my DrawerLayout.

```
// WITHOUT FOOTER VIEW
mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList)

// WITH FOOTER VIEW
mDrawerContent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerContent)
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerContent)
```

Comment: You have to pass mDrawerContent to closeDrawer and isDrawerOpen.