# Adding multiple Views to NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I'm working on `NavigationDrawer` that has a `FrameLayout` as the first child, and a ListView as the second. I've successfully populated a list of items I want programmatically. Now, I want a little bit of modification. I want another list populated inside the navigation drawer but I want it to be bottom-aligned. I looked at a couple of examples but couldn't make it work. 
Can you tell me how can I make it work?
Here's my main Navigation layout (`activity_navigation.xml`)

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#111"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My individual list itmes file (`listview_item_row.xml`)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/navigation_drawer_list_item_selector"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewIcon"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity class, I'm programatically setting layout this way:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

ObjectDrawerItem[] drawerItem = new ObjectDrawerItem[3];
drawerItem[0] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_speedometer, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[0]);
drawerItem[1] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_place, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[1]);
drawerItem[2] = new ObjectDrawerItem(R.drawable.ic_price, mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[2]);

DrawerItemCustomAdapter adapter = new DrawerItemCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.listview_item_row, drawerItem);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);        
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

How can I make another list just the way I'm creating the current one? 
I want it to look like this:
[image]
(picture took from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156476/how-to-put-list-items-at-the-bottom-of-list-view-in-navigation-drawer-like-fours))

Kind of new to the Android world. Thank you in advance. 
**Update:** I was able to nest my ListView inside a LinearLayout, then created another ListView inside that LinearLayout. Now, how do I assign ListView items to the bottom ListView controller?

Answer (score 0):

Use a RelativeLayout for your drawer rather than the ListView itself, embed your list view in there aligned to the top then stick another ListView in there assigned to the bottom.

For example:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/top_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParent_left="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParent_left="true"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

Comment: Did that. But when I passed the ListView `mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);`, I received a cast exception.

Comment: If have to see the code there to understand the exception, this approach does work.

Comment: I got `LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams` when I added a RelativeLayout as ListView's parent and in that layout, added another RelativeLayout with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: Could you provide a sample XML layout with your solution? And how can I add that to the drawer without it causing exceptions?

Comment: Check the view id you assigned to the list. This sounds like you (correctly) named the new relative layout R.id.left_drawer, but you are retrieving it as a list. You'd need to retrieve the list using the correct id.

Comment: But, `left_drawer` is a ListView.

Comment: I think you are missing what I'm saying: your to level container for the left drawer (alignment=start) needs to be a layout. You put your lists inside it. Right now you are setup so your left drawer is only a single list.

Comment: I'm getting your point, I'm just having a hard time implementing it. Could you provide some form of sample as to how it would work?

Comment: Just revised my answer with an example.  RelativeLayout is your "left drawer" container.  Your lists are within it and put at top and bottom.

Comment: Thank you, Larry. I was able to achieve the same with two `ListView`'s nested inside a `LinearLayout`. I just want to know how to add them in my drawer like I was able to with one ListView.

Comment: You are very welcome, I'm glad you were able to get it going.

Comment: I would still need them to add to the drawer, though. I'm lost there. Prettttty new to Android.

Comment: See the layout I put in my answer. There would be 2 lists in the left drawer, one anchored at the top and one at the bottom.

Comment: I would have to fill `bottom_list` with an adapter first like I did for the only ListView element. I can't seem to do that for both.

Comment: You can do two separate adapters, the system doesn't care how many you make. I've used this pattern before with no problems.

Comment: I tried that without any success. Could you provide code specific to adding multiple adapters to the drawer layout? Appreciate your help.