# How to add button functions to the navigation drawer

Tags: android

I am hoping there is a way to actually add buttons to the navigation drawer, I would really like to make an app based in that. You can also check out pics of the rendering result, and also where I want to put buttons.

[image]
This is my code where I want to put buttons in:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group>
<item android:checkableBehavior="single"/>
    <item android:title="Εκκλησίες Παλιαχώρας" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/church"
        android:title="Άγιος Χαράλαμπος" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@drawable/church"
        android:title="Τίμιος Σταυρός" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:icon="@drawable/church"
        android:title="Παναγία του Γιαννούλη" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:icon="@drawable/church"
        android:title="Αγία Βαρβάρα" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage1"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Γεώργιος ο Καθολικός" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage2"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Επισκοπή" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage3"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Άννα" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage4"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιοι Θεώδοροι" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage5"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Νικόλαος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage6"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Κήρυκος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage7"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Στυλιανός" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage8"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιοι Δημήτριος και Γεώργιος του Κάστρου" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage9"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Ελευθέριος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage10"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Μηνάς" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage11"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Μακρίνα" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage12"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Κυριακή" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage13"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Ταξιάρχης Μιχαήλ" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage14"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Ζαχαρίας" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage15"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Κρυφτή" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage16"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Ιωάννης Θεολόγος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage17"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Σπυρίδων" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage18"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Νικόλαος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage19"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιοι Ανάργυροι" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage20"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Κοίμηση της Αγίας Άννης" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage21"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Αγία Αικατερίνη" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage22"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Δημήτριος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage23"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Κοίμησις Θεοτόκου" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage24"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Μεταμόρφωση του Σωτήρος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage25"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Ταξιάρχης Μιχαήλ (2)" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage26"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Τίμιος Πρόδρομος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage27"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Ευθύμιος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage28"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Γεώργιος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage29"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Στέφανος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage30"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Αθανάσιος" />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage31"
            android:icon="@drawable/church"
            android:title="Άγιος Νικόλαος Μαυρίκας" />
    </group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the usual menu items ? Also add the pictures

Comment: If I click on them they don't do anything, is there a way I can hook them up with other layouts as buttons?

Comment: u better use listview or recyclerview ..

Answer (score 0):

Actually those are not buttons. You can use list view or recyclerview. I have found something that might help you. 
[How to put list items at the bottom of list view in Navigation Drawer like Foursquare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156476/how-to-put-list-items-at-the-bottom-of-list-view-in-navigation-drawer-like-fours)

Comment: I would like users to click one of the categories there and open another activity.

Comment: you can use Intent to open an activity.

Comment: like this,  `startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));`

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout in the navigation drawer xml file, and add the image button inside that Relative layout.